# recursive 7Zip unzip and rename is sub directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip, 7-zip, archiving

I have a root directory with many different sub-directories that have .zip files in them (example below). I need a batch/.cmd/etc to unzip the zip files in their sub directories and rename the extracted file (a .tif) the same as the zip file. I have researched around and found the following code, however this will only work when placed in the sub-directories. Not the parent folder. How to I make this code work through all the sub-directories as explained?

**Example File Structure**

C:\This\Is\Random\Parent\Sub\Sub\1234.zip {ABCD.tif}

**What I'm Looking for**
C:\This\Is\Random\Parent\Sub\Sub\1234.tif

```
set work=%temp%\%random%%random%%random%%random%
mkdir "%work%" || goto :eof

for %%A in ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') do (
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o"%work%" "%%~A"
for %%F in ("%work%\*") do move "%%~F" "%%~nA%%~xF"
)

rmdir "%work%"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make the following changes to achieve what I was looking for

```
set work=%temp%\%random%%random%%random%%random%
mkdir "%work%" || goto :eof

for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') do (
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%work%" "%%~I"
for %%F in ("%work%\*") do move "%%~F" "%%~nI%%~xF"
)

rmdir "%work%"
```

Only issue now is ".zip" is included in the name of the extracted .tif. Help resolving that would be appreciated

Comment: I posted an earlier version of the code. The "A" is replaced with "I" in the second loop as "%%-nI%%~xF" this makes the tif unzip to the parent dir with the correct extension of just .tif . "%%I%%xF" extracts them to the correct subfolders but brings the extension .zip.tif.

Comment: That saves them correctly as just the .tif extension, but does not preserve the file structure and unzips them all to the parent directory

Comment: In substituting "%%~FnI.tif" for "%%~nI%%~xf" in the original code the result is the .tif is extracted in the correct subfolder with the .zip.tif file extension.

Comment: I ran the code exactly how you have it in the last link [link](https://justpaste.it/1coa6). It ran and did not move the extracted file into the correct folder. there was and error. (attached) [link](https://justpaste.it/1coa1)

Comment: I ran the last version you suggested; again it's giving the `The system cannot find the file specified.` error. In clarification of the standards, The data originates on a website, I wrote a python scrape that downloads the .zip files (Over 500,000 .zip files). The python script creates directories based on the Public Land Survey, first by Township then Section where there could be multiple unique .zip's. ex.) `C:\\data\Township\Section\ABC.zip`. Within the .zip there is 1 tif file named `1234.tif`  the file needs to be extracted in the correct section folder with the name `ABC.tif`

Comment: Okay, I took a quick peek and now I see the nested loop is needed before the file within the zip file does not have the same name as the zip file but you want it to be renamed to the same name as the zip file. Then that is correct that you need the other nested loop to get the names of the extracted tif images so you can then rename. You are absolutely correct!!

Comment: Its working perfectly except for the .zip being in the name when it is moved back.